# ESP8266Audio with multiple .wav file encoded in hex

Tags: c, audio, esp8266

I'm working on a script that will play multiple.wav encoded files in the ESP8266 using the ESP8266Audio library. I need to play multiple audio streams with different time stamps; that's why I am asking for it. Please do note that the hardware is ESP32-8266 and TIP 120 transistor.

```
#include <Arduino.h>    
#include "AudioFileSourcePROGMEM.h"
#include "AudioGeneratorWAV.h"
#include "AudioOutputI2SNoDAC.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// VIOLA sample taken from https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Sound_Examples.html
#include "viola.h"
#include "viola02.h"

AudioGeneratorWAV *wav;
AudioFileSourcePROGMEM *file;

AudioOutputI2SNoDAC *out;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.printf("WAV start\n");

  audioLogger = &Serial;
  out = new AudioOutputI2SNoDAC();  
  //  out02 = new AudioOutputI2SNoDAC();
  //  out -> SetGain(0.08);
}

void Play(const void *data, uint32_t len) {  
  file = new AudioFileSourcePROGMEM( data, len );
  wav = new AudioGeneratorWAV();
  wav->begin(file, out);
  delay(3000);
  while (true) {
    if (wav->isRunning()) {
      if (!wav->loop()) wav->stop();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("WAV done\n");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    }
  }
}

void loop()
{
 Play(viola,sizeof(viola));
  Play(viola02,sizeof(viola02));
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIKml.png
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, it is a question man.